# 64-bit OutOfMemoryException with SqlDataAdapter

Tags: .net-3.5, 64-bit, out-of-memory, sqldataadapter

The environment is:

- 64-bit Windows
- ~50GB RAM
- .NET 3.5 SP1
- SQL 2008

The code is (essentially, from memory):

```
System.Data.DataTable table = new System.Data.DataTable();
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT XmlColumn FROM Table WHERE ID = UniqueID", Connection);
SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);

adapter.Fill(table); // OOM here
```

The single row that's being retrieved is ~750M characters/~1.5GB of text.

Here's a partial stack trace:

> System.OutOfMemoryException: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.
>   
> at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ReadPlpUnicodeChars(Char[]& buff, Int32 offst, 
>      Int32 len,
>      TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
>   
> at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ReadSqlStringValue(SqlBuffer
>      value, Byte type, Int32 length,
>      Encoding encoding, Boolean isPlp,
>      TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
>   
> at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ReadSqlValue(SqlBuffer
>      value, SqlMetaDataPriv md, Int32
>      length, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
>   
> at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.ReadColumnData()
>   
> at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.ReadColumn(Int32
>      i, Boolean setTimeout)
>   ...

In my experimenting, I've determined a .NET string can hold (exactly) 1,073,741,794 characters, so this column value is comfortably below that.

Any ideas on how this OOM can be happening ?? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Even though you have 50GB physical memory and using 64 bit OS, the maximum size of a single .NET object is still **2GB**.

Perhaps you should consider whether allocating a 1.5GB+ XML blob is really a good idea...(it rarely is)

Comment: Point taken, but that doesn't answer my question. 1.5GB is still way less than 2GB.

Comment: That's right. The actual maximum will be somewhat less than the absolute maximum. In your case, that's around the 1.5GB mark